# select filtering and removal if they are already present in the db

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

look at the picture before answering me.
that group2 is inside saved in the db with the button I open a modal that allows me to save other groups in the db and I would like that the same groups no longer appear in that select if I have already added them

[image]

form.py

```
class EserciziForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.DatiEsercizi
        exclude = ['gruppo_single']
        #fields = '__all__'
    


class GruppiForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.DatiGruppi
        exclude = ['gruppi_scheda']
```

views.py

```
def creazione(request, nome):
    scheda = get_object_or_404(Schede, nome_scheda = nome)
    eserciziFormSet = formset_factory(EserciziForm, extra = 0)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        gruppo_form = GruppiForm(request.POST, prefix = 'gruppo')
        if gruppo_form.is_valid():
            gruppo = gruppo_form.save(commit = False)
            gruppo.gruppi_scheda = scheda
            gruppoName = gruppo_form.cleaned_data['dati_gruppo']
            gruppo.save()

            esercizi_formset = eserciziFormSet(request.POST, prefix='esercizi')
            for esercizi in esercizi_formset:
                esercizi_instance = esercizi.save(commit = False)
                esercizi_instance.gruppo_single = get_object_or_404(DatiGruppi, gruppi_scheda = scheda.id, dati_gruppo = gruppoName)
                esercizi_instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    else:

        gruppo_form = GruppiForm(prefix = 'gruppo')
        esercizi_formset = eserciziFormSet(prefix='esercizi')

    context = {'scheda' : scheda, 'gruppo_form' : gruppo_form, 'esercizi_formset': esercizi_formset}
    return render(request, 'crea/passo2.html', context
```

models.py

```
class DatiGruppi(models.Model):
  giorni_settimana_scelta = [
    ("LUNEDI","Lunedì"),
    ("MARTEDI","Martedì"),
    ("MERCOLEDI","Mercoledì"),
    ("GIOVEDI","Giovedì"),
    ("VENERDI","Venerdì"),
    ("SABATO","Sabato"),
    ("DOMENICA","Domenica")
  ]
  giorni_settimana = MultiSelectField(choices = giorni_settimana_scelta,default = '-')
  dati_gruppo = models.ForeignKey(
    Gruppi,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'dati_gruppo')
  gruppi_scheda = models.ForeignKey(Schede,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'gruppi_scheda')


class Schede(models.Model):
  nome_scheda = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  data_inizio = models.DateField()
  data_fine = models.DateField()
  utente = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'utente')
```

Comment: What king of view are you use to render the modal ? Show us the `views.py` and the `form.py` files

Answer (score 0):

**You can override a form field before instantiate it like this :**

*views.py*

```
from django import forms

if request.method == "POST":
    # Post logic here
else:
    
    # We try to retrieve group that the current user is not yet in.
    # Not your logic, but to sum up, you have to retrieve the groups
    # which had not yet been added.
    # Use a filter that permit you to retrieve only groups which had not yet been added.
    group_to_add = Group.objects.filter(...)
    GruppiForm.base_fields['group_field'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=group_to_add)

# Instantiate the form now
# In this form, the choices are only those contained in the group_to_add queryset
form = GruppiForm(prefix = 'gruppo')
```

Comment: I entered the views and form code

Comment: this code must be put in get  request right?

Comment: Yes i'm updating the answer

Comment: sorry but that code doesn't make sense. the user creates a tab in that tab can I add groups why do I have to filter by user id?

Comment: What you have to retains is that the `queryset` attribute should be only the group that had not yet been added. **EX :** `all_groups - already_added_groups` ! Do you understand ?

Comment: yes but how can I take those inside the card and subtract them from all?

Comment: scheda = get_object_or_404(Schede, nome_scheda = nome) this is a specific scheda

Comment: Add the `DatiGruppi` model to the question too

Comment: group_to_add = DatiGruppi.objects.filter(gruppi_scheda = scheda.id) in this way I can recover the groups inside that tab now how can I tell them not to put them there?

Comment: I hope you really manage to resolve this doubt of mine