# query that must exclude me from the whole list

Tags: django, django-views

hi i have a problem with this filter. group_to_add takes some values ​​which should filter out the problem that I don't want those values ​​but I want the others without those.
I would like to find a way to take those values ​​and subtract them from others.

```
group_to_add = DatiGruppi.objects.filter(gruppi_scheda = scheda.id)
GruppiForm.base_fields['dati_gruppo'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = group_to_add)
```

I asked a similar question I leave the link
[select filtering and removal if they are already present in the db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568578/select-filtering-and-removal-if-they-are-already-present-in-the-db/69568882?noredirect=1#comment122965709_69568882)

models

```
class Schede(models.Model):
  nome_scheda = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  utente = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'utente')

class DatiGruppi(models.Model):
  dati_gruppo = models.ForeignKey(Gruppi,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'dati_gruppo')
  gruppi_scheda = models.ForeignKey(Schede,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'gruppi_scheda')


class Gruppi(models.Model):
  nome_gruppo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have this tab where inside there are saved data groups that contain groups that are inside a select the correct exclusion would be

```
group_to_add = Gruppi.objects.exclude(dati_gruppo = 147)
```

but instead of 147 I have to put the id of the data group of that board

view

```
def creazione(request, nome):
    scheda = get_object_or_404(Schede, nome_scheda = nome)
    eserciziFormSet = formset_factory(EserciziForm, extra = 0)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        gruppo_form = GruppiForm(request.POST, prefix = 'gruppo')
        if gruppo_form.is_valid():
            gruppo = gruppo_form.save(commit = False)
            gruppo.gruppi_scheda = scheda
            gruppoName = gruppo_form.cleaned_data['dati_gruppo']
            gruppo.save()

            esercizi_formset = eserciziFormSet(request.POST, prefix='esercizi')
            for esercizi in esercizi_formset:
                esercizi_instance = esercizi.save(commit = False)
                esercizi_instance.gruppo_single = get_object_or_404(DatiGruppi, gruppi_scheda = scheda.id, dati_gruppo = gruppoName)
                esercizi_instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    else:
        group_to_add = Gruppi.objects.exclude(dati_gruppo = 147)

        GruppiForm.base_fields['dati_gruppo'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = group_to_add)
        gruppo_form = GruppiForm(prefix = 'gruppo')
        esercizi_formset = eserciziFormSet(prefix='esercizi')

    context = {'scheda' : scheda, 'gruppo_form' : gruppo_form, 'esercizi_formset': esercizi_formset}
    return render(request, 'crea/passo2.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant models together with *what* you want to filter out?

Comment: ok updated I hope you can give me a hand

Comment: what if you use `Gruppi.objects.exclude(gruppi_scheda=scheda)`. Based on the variable `sheda`, it looks like you have to exclude the `Gruppi`s with `gruppi_scheda` instead of using `dati_gruppo`.

Comment: can you share the view and the form you are using, likely you have to pass the logged in user to the form to filter with `dati_gruppo`.

Comment: view put, but the card user has already passed

Comment: filter_my_group = DatiGruppi.objects.filter(gruppi_scheda = scheda.id)
  group_to_add = Gruppi.objects.exclude(dati_gruppo = filter_my_group)

  GruppiForm.base_fields['dati_gruppo'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = group_to_add)

Comment: if I try this it gives me this error: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Comment: What about `roup_to_add = Gruppi.objects.exclude(dati_gruppo__gruppi_scheda=scheda)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you should use [**`.exclude(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) not [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter):

```
group_to_add = Gruppi.objects.exclude(
    dati_gruppo__gruppi_scheda=scheda
)
GruppiForm.base_fields['dati_gruppo'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=group_to_add)
```

Comment: I tried but nothing filters me out